# Checking a table as a constraint

Tags: sql, database

I am building a database to schedule musicians on weekends.

I have a table of the `MUS_ROSTER` which stores the musicians. And I also have a table of `INSTRUMENTS` that has the listed instruments.

I have a third table `MUS_INST` (just a linking table) that has the PK of a musician and a PK of an instrument as foreign keys. They is a unique constraint.

I then have a `MUS_SCHED` table that has the id of the INST and the ID of the MUS as well as what WK this occurs on.

A musician can only play one instrument on a week and only one instrument can be played in a week. these constraints work fine.

However I can make any instrument played by any musician because I don't know how to have the SQL check the MUS_INST table so that I can't put a drummer on guitar or vice versa.

IS there a way to set a check that the MUSID and the INSTID occur together in the MUS_SCHED

Here's a rough outline

**MUSROSTER**

- MUSID(PK)

**INSTRUMENTS**

- INSTID(PK)

**MUS_INST**

- MUSID (FK) (UNQ when tied to INSTID)
- INSTID (FK) ((UNQ when tied to MUSID)

**MUS_SCHED**

- MUSID (FK)
- INSTID (FK)
- WKNUM (UNQ with MUSID)

How do you make MUS_SCHED check that MUSID AND INSTID occur together on the MUS_INST table?

How do you make a table check that a composite key (combination) occurs on the linked table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a PK to `MUS_INST` on `MUSID` & `INSTID`.

And then add another FK on `MUS_SCHED` that references the PK on `MUS_INST`.

Comment: If I add a PK on the MUS_INST then reference it on MUS_SCHED how does that fix the problem of a MUS not having an INST skill. It would only. Currently the MUS_ID and MUS_INST are a composite key on that table.  by adding a new key I don't see how that helps without already knowing the values in the other two attributes.

Comment: Because the FK on `MUS_SCHED` would enforce the requirement that any combination of `MUSID` and `INSTID` entered in the schedule table MUST already exist in the `MUS_INST` table.   Therefore you would never be able to schedule a musician to play an instrument he doesn't play.

Comment: Got it, Thank you kindly